# Python Webscraping Encoding

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, decode, url-encoding

I can't seem to get the program to recognize the u'\xe9' (i.e. "é"). It seems to be reading the page in ascii, which is probably the problem. So it can't print "coupé correctly." Any ideas how to fix this?

```
from lxml import html
import requests

new_list = []
page=requests.get('http://www.carfolio.com/specifications/models/?man=557')
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
model_name = tree.xpath('//span[@class="model name"]/text()'.encode('utf-8'))
for elem in model_name:
    new_list.append(elem)
    if u'\xe9' in elem:
        u'\xe9'.encode('latin-1')
        print(elem)
```

I've never had to deal with encoding stuff before. I can easily cut out the elements that contain that troublesome byte, but that is cutting out data I would need. If I switch up the encoding it gives me even stranger results.

*python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import html
import requests

new_list = []
page=requests.get('http://www.carfolio.com/specifications/models/?man=557')
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
model_name = tree.xpath('//span[@class="model name"]/text()'.encode('utf-8'))
print(len(model_name))
for elem in model_name:
    for char in elem:
        if "é" not in char:
            print(char, end='')
    print(' ')
```

This at least keeps the same number of elements, just ignores that troublesome beast of a é.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
print(elem)
```

With

```
for char in elem:
    print(bytes(char, 'latin-1').decode('latin-1'), end='')
print('')
```

Or

```
print(bytes(elem, 'latin-1').decode('latin-1'), end='')
```

Comment: That still seems to give me an ascii error. I have been using atom, so it may not work correctly. I'll try sublime and python IDE.

Comment: R8 CoupTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/animachristietmaria/Documents/CarsClass.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(char, end='')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Matty I updated my answer, it should work in theory, however, we all know code doesn't always do that.